# How can I make a voice crack effect in FL Studio

Tags: sound-design, fl-studio

I'm trying to figure out a way to recreate this voice crack effect in FL Studio that I found in this video

(Timestamp from 0:5 to 0:9) I cant find any tutorials or anything online for this, all I have is that example.

Comment: You mean the squeaky voice, or the heavy bass distortion after it?

Comment: the squeaky voice

Comment: It just sounds like the voice actor can do that in falsetto to me. They might have helped it with a formant shifter, but it wouldn't surprise me if they hadn't.

Comment: so how can i make the effect?

Comment: Get a voice actor who can do it. It's not 'an effect' it's a good voice actor.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free VST called Graillon 2 Free Edition which is similar to Autotune or Pitcher in FL Studio.

It changes the pitch while keeping other properties of the vocal. Here is an example video that shows the higher pitch quite well

Step by Step:

Use a Pitcher like Autotune or a Free VST with similar capabilities and keep voice formant

Add distortion